Generating static pages fails at build time
I am new to nextjs. My application has pages that call the backend API using axios. The application is a template and it came with mocked API. For production, obviously I want to disable mocking and target my backend, but build fails because SSG tries to call API and fails. I do not want those pages to be static as underlying data will be changing a lot.
const brands = cache(async (): Promise<Brand[]> => {
  const response = await axios.get("/api/admin/brands");
  return response.data;
});


export default async function Brands() {
  // const brands = await api.brands();
  let data = await fetch("https://rentall.ai/api/admin/brands");
  let brands = await data.json();
  return <BrandsPageView brands={brands} />;
}


Error message:
status: 404,
cause: Error: Request failed with status code 404

API mock disabled and build succeeds.

This solution might help you !
Use getServerSideProps instead of calling the API directly in the page component. This ensures the API call happens on the server when the page is requested, rather than at build time.
Solution #1
import axios from 'axios';

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://rentall.ai/api/admin/brands');
    return {
      props: {
        brands: response.data,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('API call failed:', error);
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }
}

export default function Brands({ brands }) {
  return <BrandsPageView brands={brands} />;
}

You can other also use fetch on client side using useEffect react hook
